# how to store values in account object through controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have a controller.i want to execute the field values in account object.once i save the field values in vf page,the field values stored in account object.how to solve this?[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem ?? Please be clear and precise.

Comment: In save method write update acc may it will work

Comment: i want to save the values in account object corresponding fields?

Comment: hi, Shantanu Mahajan this is not working,can u modify my code?

Answer (score 0):

you need store the controller in an attribute, and in your method save call it.

EJ :

```
public ApexPage.StandardController controller;

public CONTRUSCTOR_NAME(ApexPage.StandardController controller){
    // ALL YOUR CODE
    this.controller = controller;


}

public void save(){
    // ALL YOUR CODE

    controller.save();
}
```

Another way, it can be save the account object(if you have the id you can do a update, if you haven't it you can do a insert).

EJ :

```
public void save(){
    // ALL YOUR CODE

    // Need catch a exception when we want insert/update the record because the insert/update can be fail for validation_rules,triggers,etc...
    try{
        insert/update/upsert this.acc;
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.debug(e);
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    }
}
```

Regards